# System info dialog source?

Tags: source-code

I'd like to know where I could find (in launchpad preferably) the source code of this dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: https://launchpad.net/unity-control-center

I leave you with a meaningless sentence to meet the answer length limit.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [a recent answer that gets the PID of a clicked window](https://askubuntu.com/a/498465/449), you could run this, click the window and it *should* (some thing don't work well) give you the package.

```
dpkg -S $(sed 's/\x0.*//' /proc/$(xprop _NET_WM_PID | awk '{print $NF}')/cmdline)
```

Once you have the package, it's fairly simple to find on Launchpad or through [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com).